# NSDecimalNumber multiplication weirdness

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, multiplication, nsdecimalnumber

I've seen a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576109/nsdecimalnumber-multiplication-strangeness) about this a while back, but that seemed to be because the equation used NSNumber somewhere. I've checked all my code and all I can see is that I'm using NSDecimalNumbers for my equations.

I got a JSON webservice that returns some pricing numbers.

Just after parsing them in object properties I want to run the following equation with them:

> NetPrice * ( 1 + (RawPercentage / 100)) + FixedPrice = processedNetPrice

**Update:
I changed the code to this:**

```
    NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber one];

    if (!self.netPrice || [self.netPrice isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) 
    { self.netPrice = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }

    NSDecimalNumber *nettoPrijs = self.netPrice;
    NSLog(@"self.netPrice = %@",self.netPrice);
    //Returns: self.netPrice = 89.25

    NSLog(@"nettoPrijs = %@",nettoPrijs);
    //Returns: nettoPrijs = 89.25

    if (!self.userData.BandFixed || [self.userData.BandFixed isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) 
    { self.userData.BandFixed = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }

    NSDecimalNumber *fixedPrice = self.userData.BandFixed;

    NSLog(@"self.userData.BandFixed = %@",self.userData.BandFixed);
    //Returns: self.userData.BandFixed = 0

    NSLog(@"fixedPrice = %@",fixedPrice);
    //Returns: fixedPrice = 0

    if (!self.userData.BandPercentage || [self.userData.BandPercentage isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) 
    { self.userData.BandPercentage = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }

    NSDecimalNumber *rawPercentage = self.userData.BandPercentage;

    NSLog(@"self.userData.BandPercentage = %@",self.userData.BandPercentage);
    //Returns: self.userData.BandPercentage = 0

    NSLog(@"rawPercentage = %@",rawPercentage);
    //Returns: rawPercentage = 0

    NSDecimalNumber *percentage = [rawPercentage decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:-2];
    NSLog(@"percentage = %@",percentage);
    //Returns: percentage = 0

    NSDecimalNumber *onePercent = [one decimalNumberByAdding:percentage];
    NSLog(@"onePercent = %@",onePercent);
    //Returns: onePercent = 1

    NSDecimalNumber *onePercentTimesNetPrice = [onePercent decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:nettoPrijs];
    NSLog(@"onePercentTimesNetPrice = %@",onePercentTimesNetPrice);
    //Returns: onePercentTimesNetPrice =        
    -0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000359498933794611654993903616

    NSDecimalNumber *addingFixed = [onePercentTimesNetPrice decimalNumberByAdding:fixedPrice];
    NSLog(@"addingFixed = %@",addingFixed);
    //Returns: addingFixed =  
    -0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000359498933794611654993903616
```

If I change:

```
NSDecimalNumber *onePercentTimesNetPrice = [onePercent decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:nettoPrijs];
```

to:

```
NSDecimalNumber *onePercentTimesNetPrice = [nettoPrijs decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:onePercent];
```

it crashes:

```
-[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84ad160
```

Comment: Try to focus your question. For me it's to long to get my head around during the few minutes I have during work.

Comment: Edited it for you. Hopefully this is more focused :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't see what you mean by "this".

Comment: How come: 
89.25 * ( 1+ ((null)/100) )+ (null) = -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000133763189343321587712 ?

Comment: Why do you need to use `NSDecimalNumber` in the first place?  They are pain in the rear to use.

Comment: Tell me about it! Got any better alternative? I read at CIMGF that you should always use NSDecimalNumbers for money-related stuffs. I'm quite new to Obj-C, so I could be wrong though :).

Comment: What's wrong with `float` or `double`?  They are simple, fast and work as expected.

Comment: Well, because of [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/) :"If you are dealing with currency at all, then you should be using NSDecimalNumber." and [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) :"If you really need your results to add up exactly, especially when you work with money: use a special decimal datatype."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your NSLog() output shows, `self.userData.RawPercentage` and `self.userData.FixedPrice` are `nil`, i.e. are not allocated + initialized as `NSDecimalNumber` objects.

`nil` cannot be used to represent the decimal number zero!

In fact, when I try your code,

```
NSDecimalNumber *custPrice1 = [oneWithNet decimalNumberByAdding:priceFixed];
```

crashes because `priceFixed` is nil.

So you should check the code where these variables are initialized and make sure that they point to valid `NSDecimalNumber` objects.

---

**UPDATE:** The error message

```
-[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84ad160
```

shows that `nettoPrijs` is a `NSNumber` object and not a `NSDecimalNumber`. The following simplified code shows what happens if you try to multiply a `NSDecimalNumber` with a `NSNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber one];
id price = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:89.25];
NSDecimalNumber *product = [one decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:price];
NSLog(@"product = %@", product);
// Output:
// product = -0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000221166721562906606351581184
```

(I have no idea why this doesn't crash or produce some error message.) 
It works correctly if you multiply with a `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"89.25"];
product = [one decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:price];
NSLog(@"product = %@", product);
// Output:
// product = 89.25
```

So I assume that `self.netPrice` is a `NSNumber` object which has to be converted to a `NSDecimalNumber`. The same may apply to the other number objects.

Comment: I use

`if (!property || property == NULL || [property isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) 
        {
            property = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        }`

blocks before all of those to check if it returns nil, and then make it `[NSDecimalNumber zero]`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @VincentVeldkamp `!property` and `property == NULL` are the same test.

Comment: In that case I cannot reproduce the problem, my output is "custPrice: 89.25".

Comment: I'll check my code again and try and check where it goes wrong. Will fix the double test.
Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

```
- (void) doMath
{
    NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber one];
    NSLog(@"Band: %@ one = %@",self,one);
    if (!self.netPrice || [self.netPrice isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { self.netPrice = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }
    NSDecimalNumber *nettoPrijs = self.netPrice;
    NSLog(@"self.netPrice = %@",self.netPrice);
    NSLog(@"nettoPrijs = %@",nettoPrijs);
    if (!self.userData.BandFixed || [self.userData.BandFixed isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { self.userData.BandFixed = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }
    NSDecimalNumber *fixedPrice = self.userData.BandFixed;
    NSLog(@"self.userData.BandFixed = %@",self.userData.BandFixed);
    NSLog(@"fixedPrice = %@",fixedPrice);
    if (!self.userData.BandPercentage || [self.userData.BandPercentage isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { self.userData.BandPercentage = [NSDecimalNumber zero]; }
    NSDecimalNumber *rawPercentage = self.userData.BandPercentage;
    NSLog(@"self.userData.BandPercentage = %@",self.userData.BandPercentage);
    NSLog(@"RawPercentage = %@",rawPercentage);
    NSDecimalNumber *percentage = [rawPercentage decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:-2];
    NSLog(@"percentage = %@",percentage);
    NSDecimalNumber *onePercent = [one decimalNumberByAdding:percentage];
    NSLog(@"onePercent = %@",onePercent);
```

**NSDecimalNumber *gertje = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:nettoPrijs.decimalValue];
** 
NSDecimalNumber *onePercentTimesNetPrice = [gertje decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:onePercent];**

```
    NSLog(@"onePercentTimesNetPrice = %@",onePercentTimesNetPrice);
    NSDecimalNumber *addingFixed = [onePercentTimesNetPrice decimalNumberByAdding:fixedPrice];
    NSLog(@"addingFixed = %@",addingFixed);
}
```

Thanks for all your help!