# iPhone - Store float in SQLite thru CoreData

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, floating-point

I store a float number in my SQLite (through core data) like this:

`unit.conversion = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.001];`

When I look at the SQLite database the value is 0.0010000000474974513

unit.conversion is an optional float in my datamodel...

What's wrong with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that what you are seeing is correct (as already answered) and you are not happy with this: You can use NSDecimalNumber.  A quick google search provided:

- [A Cocoa is my girlfriend post](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/) (this might fit your situation exactly)
- [A cocoa with love post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/square-root-numerical-fun-with.html)
- [A tutorial about the different cocoa number containers](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/057_NSNumber_NSDecimalNumber.pl)
- [A stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453691/how-use-nsdecimalnumber)

NSDecimalNumber allows you to do decimal arithmetic like how a financial institution would like you to do math.  *Warning*: it is a little obnoxious to work with since all math operators are messages.

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers are not (always) exact representations - they are approximations.

See [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for the background.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I need also a solution

Comment: 0.001 and the value you have in the database are, for most purposes, the same thing, as the above link probably explains. What exactly would you expect as a solution?

Comment: the problem is that when I ll do some multiplications, I ll get float numbers with strange values...

Comment: But you probably won't; you're going to be rounding for display, right?