# Precision error using NSNumberFormatter numberFromString

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nsnumberformatter

Why does the following code produce "numberFromString = 9.390000000000001" rather than "numberFromString = 9.39"?

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"$##0.00"];
[numFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-$##0.00"];
NSNumber *nTCA = [numFormatter numberFromString:@"$9.39"];

NSLog(@"numberFromString = %@", nTCA);
```

I get the above results on OS X 10.6 and iOS 4.3.3.

What's the best way to correct this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are running into an error as a result of using floating-point precision. The way to fix this is to use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `NSNumber`. There's a great post about this [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/).

`NSDecimalNumber` has a [`+ decimalNumberWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString%3a) method. Would that suffice for your purposes?

Comment: The only problem with that article is that the author forgets that `NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber` and so responds to things like `+numberWithInt:` and `+numberWithDouble:`  You don't need to use `+decimalNumberWithMantissa:exponent:isNegative:` to create them from primitives.

Comment: @JeremyP Actually, since `+numberWithInt:` and `+numberWithDouble:` and the like return an `NSNumber*`, I'm pretty sure you can't use them to create `NSDecimalNumber*`. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453691/how-use-nsdecimalnumber

Comment: @Nate Thorn: `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt: x]` will give you an `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: @Nate Thorn: And even if it doesn't, the equivalent `-initWith...` methods definitely should.

Comment: @JeremyP Well, it looks like it's a question of API. The API states that the `+numberWithInt:` methods return an `NSNumber*` (unspecialized) so *technically* you can't assume that they'll be `NSDecimalNumber*`s. That being said, I just ran a quick test and it looks like they definitely are returning `NSDecimalNumber*`s.

So in the end, I guess it comes down to a question of philosophy. Do you blindly follow the API to the letter, or do you just cast the darn thing and get on with life? :)

Comment: @Nate Thorn: I also tried the same test and got an NSDecimalNumber back.  However, on reflection, I think I would agree with you and stick with the `-initWith...` methods just for safety.  I just looked up the `+array` method of NSArray, which can be sent to `NSMutableArray` to get a mutable array and its return type is id (and it also explicitly says it is used by subclasses in the documentation).