# How to properly display currency iPhone/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, currency

I am trying to properly display properly formatted currencies from long values.  I am using NSNumberFormatter however it seems to be cutting off my decimal places where the cents would go.

For example, if I have a long value of 1203 (cents) I want it to have a fixed point format (like 12.03).  Here is what I have done:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = "USD";
formatter.multiplier = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
long currencyAmount = 1203;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:currencyAmount];
[label setText:[formatter stringFromNumber:number]];
```

I am getting this output $12.00 but I want $12.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. This will properly format a long/long long value to a currency.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = "USD";
long currencyAmount = 1203;
NSDecimalNumber *wrappedCurrencyAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:currencyAmount exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];
[label setText:[formatter stringFromNumber:wrappedCurrencyAmount]];
```

Answer (score 2):

To think of an integer cut-off bug inside of `NSNumberFormatter` is crazy speculation but have you tried the default multiplier of one and dividing your currency amount after conversion to float by 100 yourself?

**EDIT**: For this workaround the following post suggests the use of `NSDecimalNumber` to avoid rounding problems. [NSNumberFormatter to format currency not working for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545290/nsnumberformatter-to-format-currency-not-working-for-floats)

Comment: Yea I got that solution working but I wanted to figure out if there was a built in way within the NSNumberFormatter to do this automatically.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Definitely interesting question. +1

Comment: I found a solution. Will post the response now.

Comment: And how is that different...?

Comment: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/