# iOS: Correct NSDecimalNumber calculations

Tags: objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

First time using NSDecimalNumber, so I've wondered do I really need to create so many objects? In my method I want to calculate monthly costs out of daily costs. The monthly costs are stored in `self.sumPerMonth` and the parameter `costs` is the daily cost value. So I want to add to my monthly costs `30 * costs`. Is this the easiest way to do that?

```
[self.sumPerMonth decimalNumberByAdding:[costs decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"30"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSDecimalNumber` is immutable so yes, you need to create a new object each time you do an operation.

The clumsiness of dealing with the objects is the compromise you make for getting **base-10 calculations without loss of precision and with predictable rounding behavior**.

[Beware of mixing `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453691/how-use-nsdecimalnumber).

A little reading: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdecimalnumber.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the way to go using `NSDecimalNumber`.

If there's valid reason to be concerned about number of objects created you could switch to the plain `NSDecimal` struct type. The difference is that `NSDecimal` is mutable.

Comment: @MichiZH It means that the value of a `NSDecimalNumber` can't be changed, whereas the value of an `NSDecimal` can.

Comment: Ok so my way of calculating is okay like this? I mean the objects not needed anymore will be deleted anyway right?

Comment: @MichiZH As I said, your code is fine. Everything will be cleaned up.

Comment: Ok thx. One last question: I've used double before (shame on me :-) with currencies in coredata. I've calculated the sum of relationsships like this: [self.hasTransactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"]. Can I do this as well with the Decimal type?