# Type casting, why is it so verbose? Or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDecimalNumber and an NSInteger. I want to multiply the former by the latter, so I'll have to convert the integer. This is what I came up with, after some trial and error.

```
NSDecimalNumber *factor = (NSDecimalNumber*) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInteger:myInteger];
```

It feels like I'm really driving the point home:

1. Hi there, I want an NSDecimalNumber, let's call it *factor*.
2. By the way, just so you know, I want that to be an NSDecimalNumber, if that'd be possible.
3. So could you give me an NSDecimalNumber? Here, I'll give you an integer to use as a source.

Is it supposed to be this verbose? Or am I messing up somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(NSDecimalNumber*)` type-cast is "necessary" because `+numberWithInteger:` is an `NSNumber` method that returns an `NSNumber` object. However, this is actually going to cause problems, because it's returning an `NSNumber` object, **not** an `NSDecimalNumber`. ([How to use NSDecimalNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453691/how-use-nsdecimalnumber))

To get your integer into a decimal number, simply do this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *factor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal: [@(myInteger) decimalValue]];
```

It's still fairly verbose but two things to bear in mind:

- Objective-C is very verbose, by design.
- `NSDecimalNumber` in not intended for basic integer arithmetic, it's intended for use with numbers that are typically represented using scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

The API you call is a `NSNumber` convenience constructor which returns an `NSNumber` -- not necessarily an `NSDecimalNumber`. A convenience constructor does not need to return a type of the class you message, but an instance of the declared return type. Because `NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber`, an explicit downcast is required when assigning an `NSNumber` to an `NSDecimalNumber`.

If a library writer intended to specify the expectation you have in mind (to return an instance of the class you have messaged), `instancetype` would be used for the return type. Unfortunately, it is a rather new keyword and does not exist in all places it possibly could exist. If `instancetype` had been used, the cast would not be necessary.

Before `instancetype` existed, a simple `id` was the convention. With `id`, no cast is required and no type checking performed when assigning/initializing a variable of an Objective-C type. For example: `NSArray * array = [NSString string];` would not be flagged by the compiler if the return type were `id`, but it would be flagged if the return type were `instancetype`. `NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString string];` would be flagged by neither, but it would be flagged if `+string`'s return type were declared `+ (NSString *)string;`.